# Search keywords in PDF and give page number

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using Adobe reader x1 and I create a macro in  excel which search keywords in PDF and give page number where it find the keywords. I have found a macro which search the PDF but that macro only work on OCR. Is it possible to create the macro which also search keywords in PDF using Adobe reader XI.

Comment: I've never done this task before, but this site might offer a solution https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2014/05/pdf-search-through-vba.html

Comment: I have already tested the code which is given in the link but that code only work on Acrobat professional. The code is giving me error active x component while running the code in reader. Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: Sorry but I've never attempted to do this before. It seems like something that would be solve-able by googling around